# Run tests only in test folder

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a test project in java, that runs all tests found in the projects listed as dependencies for this project.

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClassnameFilters({ "com.example.*_Test" })
public class AllRegularTests {
   // nothing to do
}
```

My tests are usually in the `test/` folder not in the `src/`

How can I  make the test suite look only for classes in `test/`, and not in `src/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with the testSourceDirectory definition but I'm not sure.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things seems to be wrong here :

1. By default Maven uses the following naming conventions when looking for tests to run: Test* *Test *TestCase Your test class doesn't follow these conventions. You should rename it or configure Maven Surefire Plugin to use another pattern for test classes.
2. unit test code should put under the test folder, it can not be recognized as test class if you put it under the main folder. 
   eg.

**Wrong** /my_program/src/main/java/NotTest.java

**Right** /my_program/src/test/java/MyTest.java

Also, check if your test classes directory (e.g. src/test/java) corresponds to directory listed in property in your pom.xml under property. Took me a while to find that.

Comment: @adi did the solution worked for u ? or you still facing any issue?